# Prove that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}$ does not exist.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}$$ does not exists.

To do so, I'm trying to find two different sequences $\{\bar{a_n}\}$, $\{\bar{b_n}\}$ such that $\{\bar{a_n}\} \to (0, 0), \{\bar{b_n}\} \to (0, 0)$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\bar{a_n}) = L_1 \not = L_2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\bar{b_n})$$
Def. Let $f: A\subseteq \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}, (x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ accumulation point of $A.$ We say that $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (x_0, x_0)} f(x, y) = L \Longleftrightarrow$$ if $\forall \{\bar{a_n}\}$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \bar{a_n} \in A, \bar{a_n}\not = (x_0, y_0)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bar{a_n} = (x_0, y_0),$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(\bar{a_n}) = L$$

Answer (score 3):

The limits along the lines $y=kx$ exist but are not all equal.

If you want to take sequences, take $a_n^{(k)}=(1/n, k/n)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n=\left(\frac1n,0\right)$ and your limit will be $0$. But if you take $b_n=\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$, then your limit will be $\frac12$.

Comment: But $sin(1/n^2)$ and $sin(2/n^2)$ is $0$ and this indeterminate my function, is it right?? Or why not?

Comment: Won't the second limit be $\frac 12$?

Comment: @Someone Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$, we have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1/n^2)}{2/n^2}=\frac12.$$

Comment: @abiessu Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: omg!!!! i fotgot this!! Thank you so much!